# Copy folder in docker entrypoint sh script produces wrong folder name

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, sh

I have a small docker based project and I want to copy my local .ssh folder inside then modify folder permissions.

1. In the docker-compose.yml I mount my .ssh folder to the container's tmp/.ssh folder.
2. Then on startup I copy the contents of tmp/.ssh to root/.ssh and change the folder permissions.
   *(This step is needed because when would install my PHP packages via composer, it would complain that the folder permissions are too open)*

Unfortunately there is something wrong with my .sh script because the folder's name what it creates in /root looks like this: **'.ssh'$'\r'**

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  sandbox:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ~/.ssh:/tmp/.ssh
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8060:80"
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#1000
      - APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
      - APACHE_PID_FILE=/tmp/apache2.pid
      - APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
      - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache-buster

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY vhost-configs/vhost.local.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY vhost-configs/vhost.local.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
RUN rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

EXPOSE 80

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh && chmod +x /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cp -R /tmp/.ssh /root/.ssh
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: `'.ssh'$'\r'` your file may have dos line endings

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk that helped. I used: dos2unix /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh and then the script got fixed. Posted the solution as  answer.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-entrypoint.sh file was created on windows and contained dos line endings.

I installed dos2unix and converted the file inside the container:

```
RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix


RUN dos2unix /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```